# Triggering a DAG manually runs it on UTC schedule

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I recently upgraded my airflow to 2.2.4. Now, from my admin console when I hit trigger DAG, it goes to queued. It does not immediately run but runs after 7 hours. The airflow scheduler and server are in the PDT timezone (7 hours behind UTC) so why is it triggering the DAG 'now' as UTC 'now' and not the set PDT timezone?

My airflow.cfg has `default_timezone` and `default_ui_timezone` set to `America/Los_Angeles`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `default_timezone` in the Airflow configuration. By default its value is UTC.
See : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#default-timezone

Comment: Already set to America\Los_Angeles. Tried setting it to system as well, did not work. Set default_ui_timezone too.

Comment: @ParthShah Do you mean 'America/Los_Angeles' not 'America\Los_Angeles'?

Comment: Yes, my bad. 'America/Los_Angeles'. I also tried it with 'system' as my box is here. No luck.

Comment: @ParthShah Did u find the solution? I got problem too :((